# Meet an error " ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 4) are incompatible"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Can anyboday help me on this error?  the total files are 2204 to 5 classes. and 1764 files for training. Thanks advanced.

this is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import pathlib
data_dir = r"/root/data_Camera"
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
rock = list(data_dir.glob('rock/*'))
print(rock[0])
PIL.Image.open(str(rock[0]))
img_height, img_width = 400,2000
batch_size = 32
trains_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split = 0.2,
  subset = "training",
  seed = 123,
  label_mode = 'categorical',
  image_size = (img_height, img_width),
  batch_size = batch_size)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    label_mode = 'categorical',
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)
class_names = trains_ds.class_names
print(class_names)
resnet_model = Sequential()
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, 
                                                  input_shape=(400,2000,3),
                                                  pooling='avg', 
                                                  classes = 5, 
                                                  weights = 'imagenet')
for layer in pretrained_model.layers: 
    layer.trainable=False
resnet_model.add(pretrained_model)
resnet_model.add(Flatten())
resnet_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
resnet_model.add(Dense(4,activation='softmax'))
resnet_model.summary()
resnet_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
epochs = 10
history= resnet_model.fit(
    trains_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epochs)
```

and I meet the error is:
ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 4) are incompatible
I also add the file code to here. https://github.com/CallaDai/Tensorflow.git you can check it out. thank you!

Comment: Change `Dense(4,activation='softmax')` to `Dense(5,activation='softmax')`

Comment: The reason of getting this error is you are giving a wrong shape of label array to your model. It is is expecting an array of shape (None, 5), while you are giving an array of shape (None, 4). This may be because your dataset has 5 classes. Please change your last dense layer as suggested by AloneTogether. For more details please refer similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65723064/14290681). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having recently faced a similar problem consider using `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead of `loss='categorical_crossentropy`.  The error may occur because 'categorical_crossentropy' works on a one-hot encoded target, while 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' works on an integer target.